# Sentido da expressão "recolher uma taxa" quando significa "pagar"

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

No meu entendimento e lógica, "recolher" significa "acrescentar à quantia atual em posse do indivíduo", e o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/recolher) e [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=recolher), dentre os outros significados, confirmam isso. Porém, um, aparentemente, eufemismo muito utilizado nos meios formais para dizer que se precisa *pagar*, é a palavra "recolher". Exemplos (ambos significando "pagar"):

> E depois deverá comparecer aqui para recolher uma taxa de R$ 10,00.
>
> É obrigatório que todo cidadão faça o recolhimento dos seus impostos.

O que eu não entendo é por que não é dito algum sinônimo com o sentido de "subtrair" ao invés de um antônimo. Os dicionários apenas reconhecem o sentido de "acrescentar" para a palavra recolher, mas parece que essas pessoas têm a intenção de testar nosso raciocínio lógico dizendo que temos que acrescentar um decremento ao nosso dinheiro (Dinheiro + (-Quantia)).

Mas por que isso?

Comment: lol, tens que recolher dinheiro da tua carteira para entregar ao fisco. Podes pôr links a exemplos reais?

Comment: Você recolhe os impostos, ou taxas, ou multas **ao Tesouro** Nacional (estadual, municipal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é um uso peregrino e pioneiro da palavra ***recolher***. Em termos muito latos, *recolher* significa ‘colher, juntar ou receber e depois guardar’, como recolher o gado no estábulo, recolher a roupa do estendal, recolher informações.

Falando-se de impostos e taxas, *recolher* significa ‘cobrar’; não significa ‘pagar’. Veja-se [*recolher* no Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/recolher)

> **10**. Arrecadar, receber [td. : *Recolher impostos*]

Ou no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003):

> **12.1** *t.d.* fazer cobrança de; receber, arrecadar <*recolher impostos*> <*não era ela quem recolhia os alugueres dos seus apartamentos*>

Agora, como é que este uso surgiu? Posso apenas especular. Frequentemente quem recolhe impostos ou outros dinheiros não os recolhe para si mesmo, mas sim para depois entregar a outro. Um exemplo do Houaiss:

> **12** *bit* aceitar, obter ou apanhar, juntando <*recolher espórtulas* [esmolas] *para a igreja*>

Neste outro exemplo, de [Bet Hwell Allan Ogot, *História Geral de África*, 2010](https://books.google.pt/books?id=t7GE3JnMYgMC&pg=PA429&dq=%22recolhimento%20de%20uma%20taxa%20real%20sobre%20as%20mercadorias%20importadas%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2me3Rw8LSAhUDrRQKHX6tBugQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22recolhimento%20de%20uma%20taxa%20real%20sobre%20as%20mercadorias%20importadas%22&f=false), evidentemente os chefes de origem cativa recolhem a taxa para o rei (ênfase minha):

> É possível também que date do reinado de Naaba Kango a criação de um corpo de chefes de mercado de origem cativa, encarregados do **recolhimento de uma taxa real** sobre as mercadorias importadas.

Ou ainda neste exemplo, de [Viviane de Oliveira Cubas, *Segurança Privada*, 2005](https://books.google.pt/books?id=cgv2flDoKwMC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=%22recolher%20uma%20taxa%22&source=bl&ots=Sy8CIofK7j&sig=VqvqMwfTPuZMHpqnBXOwb8ivGO0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH_pzPusLSAhVB6RQKHc4nBL4Q6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=%22recolher%20uma%20taxa%22&f=false), é o condomínio que tem de receber a taxa dos condóminos, ou a empresa que recebe a taxa do cliente, para depois a entregar ao estado de São Paulo:

> Dessa forma, todos os condomínios que tenham um corpo de segurança próprio ou as empresas de segurança terão que **recolher uma taxa para o estado**.

É possível que deste uso, de recolher dinheiros para entregar, ou pagar, a outro, tenha vindo esse novo uso em que recolher é usado com o significado de ‘pagar’. Nós podemos dizer que “o condomínio têm de recolher a taxa municipal”, significando que ‘tem de a cobrar aos condóminos’; subentende-se também que depois terá de entregar esse dinheiro ao município. Nesse novo uso dos teus exemplos, *recolher* perdeu o significado próprio (eu compareço e recolho a taxa? de mim mesmo, da minha carteira? quem recolhe a taxa é o funcionário) e passou a designar a ação subentendida.

Comment: Então aí seria recolher do ponto de vista da entidade, né? Mas já vi algumas vezes ser pedido que *a pessoa* recolha a taxa, por isso achei confuso. Não tenho aqui os exemplos e nem achei na internet, mas eu pesquisei e segundo [este site](http://profmariojorge.com.br/sala-de-aula/conceitos/impostos-a-pagar-x-impostos-a-recolher-quando-usar-um-ou-outro/), "recolher imposto" é quando a pessoa paga um imposto que a entidade tem que pagar. Apesar de isso não justificar o uso aparentemente contraditório do termo quando dito referindo-se à pessoa, ao invés da entidade.

Comment: Em relação ao edit, especuladamente falando, provavelmente foi isso que aconteceu, o termo teria perdido o significado por ter sido entendido errado e repassado errado, então agora se vê pessoas usando o termo "recolher" como sinônimo de "pagar", não sendo bem isso na realidade.

Comment: @Bruno, O artigo que tu linkaste diz o mesmo que eu. É possível uma entidade qualquer recolher impostos (recebê-los de outras pessoas ou entidades) para depois os entregar ao Estado. Mas *recolher* é o ato de os receber; entregá-los ao Estado já não é *recolher*; aí é o Estado que os está a recolher.

Comment: @Bruno, sim, mas é mera especulação. Por vezes grupos profissionais desenvolvem uma gíria própria. Foi com certeza isso que aconteceu com o pessoal do fisco aí no Brasil, e agora estão a usar essa gíria no seu contacto com o público. Só eles é que poderão dizer como, exatamente, chegaram a esse uso de *recolher*; mas o artigo que linkaste, com a preocupação de distinguir *pagar* de *recolher*, dá ideia que poderá ter sido isso mesmo.

Comment: Antes passavam recolhendo os impostos. Agora a própria pessoa tem de recolher e dar ao governo.

Comment: @Bruno, apenas opinião: Não me soam como sinônimos, são ações distintas embora com o mesmo resultado final. Recolher pra mim soa no sentido literal de colher, apurar, coletar, porém para um terceiro. No final tem o mesmo efeito que pagar.

Comment: Isso são eufemismos para colocar o cidadão a pagar impostos, julgando que está a poupar dinheiro, um pouco no sentido que apresentou para o caso da Igreja. Ou seja, o papel do cidadão é _recolher para o erário público_.